# How to display value of List<String> in custom class with two or more columns?

Tags: c#, rdlc

```
public class Custom
{
    int ID;
    List<String> listBuyItems;
}
```

I create a DataSet from Object shown above

If I want display listBuyItems in one table with two columns like

```
___
ID
___

listBuyItems[0] |  listBuyItems[1] 

listBuyItems[2] |  listBuyItems[3]

...
___
```

how do i get value from a List?

I really can't find out solution of getting value from listBuyItems.

please show me some hit or sample. thanks!

Comment: Hi you have to use a subreport to show the listbuyitems, take a look at this article http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2009/07/01/reporting-against-a-domain-model/

Comment: Why not use `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`?

Comment: how does Dictionary work in RDLC?can u explain some sample?thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant it. Guess that's what you're looking for

```
public class Custom
{
    int ID;
    List<String> listBuyItems;

   public string displayValue() 
   {
      string result = string.Empty;

     if(listBuyItems!= null)
     {
       foreach (var item in listBuyItems)
       {
             result +=   "|" + item;      
       }
     }
       return result;
    }
}
```